# Getting error when creating 2gp package version

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, 2gp, beta-managed-package

Getting following error

```
Add components {Profile=[Admin]} back into the package version, and create the package version again.
```

This is my current sfdx-project json of managed package :

```
"versionName": "1.2",
"versionNumber": "1.2.0.NEXT",
"ancestorVersion": "1.1.0.1"
```

And now I am creating new beta package with this:

```
"versionName": "1.3",
"versionNumber": "1.3.0.NEXT",
"ancestorVersion": "1.2.0.1"
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you enable or disable any features in the scratch org def compared with the previous version?

Comment: No .. no change

Answer (score 2):

Manageability rules do not allow you to delete components from your managed package at will.

While second-generation packaging [allows a broad scope of components to be deleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_remove_md_components.htm), you must first log a case to have component deletion made available to you:

> To request access to this feature, log a case at Salesforce Partner Community.

> After your request is approved, remove the metadata component’s source file from your Salesforce DX project, and create a package version. Test the new package version to ensure it’s working properly without the removed metadata.

Until you have this feature turned on, any uploads you attempt to perform with components removed relative to the package's ancestor version will fail.

Comment: The challenge is, issue it is complaining ({Profile=[Admin]})  doesn't even exist in my package. I don't  know where it is. It is not in my code base.

Comment: Have you checked your earlier branches and/or commits used when creating package versions (I assume you have, but just checking) to see if that profile existed in one of them? Regardless, if you enable this feature this deletion should then be allowed (despite you not knowing where it originated).

Comment: yeah I checked that.. that was my first assumption that I might have added it by mistake. but it was never there.

Comment: I was also wondering with ancestor feature, would be great if any component is deletable if we don't specify ancestorversion.

Comment: Be careful - breaking the ancestry line also breaks upgradability and loses you Security Review approval, if you have that

Comment: Oh.. good to know breaking ancestry can loose security review.. and upgradeability, yeah make sense.

Comment: I don't have security review and ancestry issue right now because I don't have any upgradeable customer.. but to resolve this package creation I was thinking of creating it without ancestor version .. but then I thought I might see the same issue in next version .. :(